# Do All Characters Start With Two Free Edges?

Tags: character-creation, savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds Deluxe Weird War II, it states under Race that all Characters start with a free Edge (because they’re all human).

Then under Edges & Hinderances, it says all characters receive a free Edge.

Is that the same Edge or an additional Edge?

Answer (score 4):

**You start with just one free edge.**

Reading *Savage Worlds Revised,* Chapter One:Character Creation (Page 12 and 13).

In the section 1) Race it mentions the same thing that you said about the human race:

> Humans are the standard race in Savage Worlds, and start play with one
> free Edge (see Step 3).

And in the section *3) Edges & Hindrances just states*

> You can take one Major Hindrance and two Minor Hindrances. A Major
> Hindrance is worth 2 points, and a Minor Hindrance is worth 1 point.

Comment: That actually is the source of my confusion. WWII pg 6 states under RACE, All characters start with a Free Edge (they're all Humans). Then WWII Pg 7 Edges & Hindrances states all characters start with a free Edge. I believe this is the same edge, but it doesn't match the text from Deluxe.

Answer (score 3):

## You Get One Free Edge

While *Weird War Two* has some additional steps and options for character creation, it builds upon the *Savage Worlds* core rules. Which means it follows those core rules.

In the *Savage Worlds* core rules (original, Revised, Explorer, Deluxe, or Adventure editions), Edges are provided by a source. That source may be Race, a setting rule, or by spending points from Hindrances.

To quote *Savage Worlds Deluxe* pages 16 & 17:

> Humans are the standard race in Savage Worlds, and start play with one free Edge (see Step 3).

And

> Characters can take Edges by balancing them out with Hindrances. You’ll find a complete list of Edges and Hindrances later in this chapter. Look for more in our Savage Settings.
> You can take one Major Hindrance and two Minor Hindrances. A Major Hindrance is worth 2 points, and a Minor Hindrance is worth 1 point.
>
>  For 2 points you can:
>
> • Choose an Edge

WW2 doesn't change that. Characters are human, and gain one free Edge because of the human racial ability. There is no Setting Rule that provides additional Edges. And the rules for Hindrance points remain the same.

---

For informational purposes: PEG Inc. (the publishers of *Savage Worlds* and *Weird War Two*) have a [forum](https://www.pegforum.com/) with a section for asking for [official answers](https://www.pegforum.com/forum/savage-worlds/official-answers-on-rules-in-pinnacle-s-settings-post-swade) to rules questions about their settings.

Comment: Yes, but their Official Answers Forum is for SWADE only. Weird War II isn't a SWADE setting, yet.

Comment: @JoeNapalm There is an official answers forum for PEG settings. Weird War II is a PEG published setting.